Square of the convergence rate $\|\hat{A}-A\|_F^2$
In a high-dimensional setting, if we have an estimator,  $\hat{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, we always try to get the convergence rate measured by matrix norms, such as $\|\hat{A}-A\|_F$.
Now, if I have obtained the convergence rate, $\|\hat{A}-A\|_F\le c\sqrt{\frac{\log p}{n}}$ with a high probability, Can I directly get the convergence rate $\|\hat{A}-A\|_F^2\le c^2{\frac{\log p}{n}}$?
Intuitively, I feel that this result is correct. If it holds, does it hold for all matrix norms? for example, the Frobenius norm and the spectral norm.

Can you be a bit more precise about what you want to show? The inequalities $a \leq b$ and $a^2 \leq b^2$ are logically equivalent for all $a, b \in \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$.
